# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, trigonometric-series

Does the numerical series $\sum \frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}$ converges ?

For the moment I have tried a discrete integration by parts but it involves the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum \sin(n^2)$ which seems complex.

Trying a comparison with an integral does not seem very useful too.

Comment: Integral test could be a good way out ...

Comment: @Math-fun I don't think the integral test can be applied to any series that changes signs infinitely, not to mention, how do you take the integral of that?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt you are right! integral test can't be applied to the this series. But the intergal $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x} dx$ can be evelauted, it just involves sine integral ...

Answer (score 7):

By [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(n^2)\ll N^{\frac{7}{12}} \log^2(N) $$
hence the given series is convergent by summation by parts.

Comment: What would be the limit of the orginal sum? Numerically it seems to be in the interval between 0.165 and 0.170. Weyl's inequality was new to me.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: once convergence is granted, an efficient numerical computation of such series is a different task, and a challenging one. My first temptation would be (like in Van Der Corput's trick) to consider the squared modulus of $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{in^2}}{n}$ and apply summation by parts and what is known on the average order of $r_2(n)$, but that seems pretty involved.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: my version of Mathematica returns a $0.17850281$ with a (not surprising) warning on the possible failure of the Euler-Maclaurin method used in the computation.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio : I have used naive summation with Accumulate[] to arrive at the graph for 2 Million terms shown in my "solution" below. The average result is significantly below your value, and, furthermore, it shows an intereresting jump structure. I cannot say to which extent the result is numerically valid.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio : I have compiled some numerical results of the limit in my solution. None is satisfactory :-(

Comment: I have a curiosity. We can say something also for the $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n^\alpha)$ with $\alpha\in R_+$

Answer (score 0):

**Attempts to calculate the limit**

Now that Jack D'Aurizio has proved the convergence of the sum

$$s_{2,1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}$$

we ask for the value of the infinite sum.

To this end we compare numerical approaches using Mathematica 8.0

*1) Accumulate[]*

Here a table of values for all $n$ to be considered is created first, then the patial sums are calculated using Accumulate[].

A strange kinky structure in the (unfinished) approach to a limit appears, hereby shedding doubt on the method and the result.

$$ \text{Accumulate[]}(s_{2,1})\simeq 0.165\tag{1}$$

[image]

*2) NSum[] with no specified method*

$$\text{NSum[]}(s_{2,1}) = 0,1785031 \tag{2}$$

Warnings:

> NIntegrate::deodiv: DoubleExponentialOscillatory returns a finite
>   integral estimate, but the integral might be divergent.
>
> NSum::emcon: Euler-Maclaurin sum failed to converge to requested error
>   tolerance.

*3) NSum[] with method AlternatingSigns*

The graph now looks promising, and the limit calculated as the average over the last $10^5$ values is

$$\text{NSum[altsigns]}(s_{2,1}) = \text{0.10446481678}\tag{3}$$

[image]

*4) Check of method AlternatingSigns*

Let us check if the method of 3) is reliable with a case in which the exact result of the limit is known

$$s_{1,1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n} = \frac{\pi - 1}{2}\simeq 1.0708$$

Unfortunately, as shown in the graph the numeric result differs significantly from the exact value.

Hence we are somewhat lost in the middle of (unappropriate) numerical methods.

[image]

*5) van der Corput*

As suggested by Jack D'Aurizio the method of van der Corput (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput%27s_method) which was specifically designed to generate estimates for exponential sums should be tried.